# Batch output filename with datetime

Tags: windows-7, cmd.exe, vbscript

I have a batch file that look like this:

```
set FOLDERTOZIP=c:\myfolder

For /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /t') do (set mydate=%%c-%%a-%%b)
For /f "tokens=1-2 delims=/:" %%a in ("%TIME%") do (set mytime=%%a:%%b)

set OUTPUTFILE=C:\myArchive %mydate% %mytime%.zip

echo Set objArgs = WScript.Arguments > _zipIt.vbs
echo InputFolder = objArgs(0) >> _zipIt.vbs
echo ZipFile = objArgs(1) >> _zipIt.vbs
echo CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").CreateTextFile(ZipFile, True).Write "PK" ^& Chr(5) ^& Chr(6) ^& String(18, vbNullChar) >> _zipIt.vbs
echo Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application") >> _zipIt.vbs
echo Set source = objShell.NameSpace(InputFolder).Items >> _zipIt.vbs
echo objShell.NameSpace(ZipFile).CopyHere(source) >> _zipIt.vbs
echo wScript.Sleep 2000 >> _zipIt.vbs

CScript  _zipIt.vbs  %FOLDERTOZIP%  %OUTPUTFILE%
```

The script fail to run mainly due to putting `%mydate% %mytime%` into the filename.

How can I get the filename output with the current datetime?

Comment: What do you *expect* `%OUTPUTFILE%` to look like? Note is currently contains spaces, so the call to your `vbs` script may see more arguments than it is expecting because of the spaces.

Comment: @DavidPostill Expect it to look like this `C:\myArchive 2015-04-16 14:57.zip`. How can I put space into the name?

Comment: I'm no expert on script/vbs but have you tried quoting %OUTPUTFILE%, ie `CScript  _zipIt.vbs  %FOLDERTOZIP%  "%OUTPUTFILE%"`?

Comment: @DavidPostill Nope, it doesn't work. It appear with the error `Microsoft VBScript runtime error: Object required: 'objShell.NameSpace(...)'`

Comment: Then I don't know what the problem is. `%OUTPUTFILE%` contains the correct value so it must be something to do with the vbs script not interpreting it correctly. Adding vbscript tag so an expert will hopefully look at it.

Comment: What is the error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems in your code. First you must quote all paths that can contain spaces.

```
CScript  _zipIt.vbs  "%FOLDERTOZIP%"  "%OUTPUTFILE%"
```

Second your zip file's name contains ':' which is not a valid character for file names. You must change that.

```
For /f "tokens=1-2 delims=/:" %%a in ("%TIME%") do (set mytime=%%a-%%b)
```

Besides that: why do you mix bat file and vbs file? Why don't you just use vbs?
And during debugging you should split lines like `echo objShell.NameSpace(ZipFile).CopyHere(source) >> _zipIt.vbs` into two lines where you first line calls `NameSpace` and stores the returned object and the second line uses the object. Of course for production code your shorter version is nicer.